# Generic Repository Pattern in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am new to Generic Repository pattern. I tried to create a sample to add, update, delete, and find method using generic repository. Find my sample code,

Generic Repository Interface and class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{        
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void SaveChanges();
}

public class DataRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private ObjectContext _context;
    private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

    public DataRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
       _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where(predicate);
    }
    public void Add(T entity)
    {
       _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }
}
```

And i used this method like below,

```
DataRepository<tblUser> _tblUser = new DataRepository<tblUser>(new SampleRepositoryEntities());
DataRepository<TestingTable> sampleRepository = new DataRepository<TestingTable>(new SampleRepositoryEntities());
public void GetRecords()
{
    var record1 = sampleRepository.Find(f => f.id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
    var record = _tblUser.Find(f => f.emailid == "karthik@abc.com").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

i can find the records using Find method from the table "TestingTable" in  SampleRepositoryEntities. Because this table has very less record around 10 records.

But i tried to find first record that match the email id from tbluser table, this table has more than 50,000 records, i couldn't get the result keep loading at this point and haven't got any exception also. What i did wrong.. Can anyone please let me clear this?

Comment: Yes, Please do not forget to mark a correct answer. This is a reason potential answers are not being posted.

Comment: I think you have to find your predicate count then get object of particular predicate                                              public int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate){}

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I implement the generic repository with EF, I use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead of `Func<T, bool>` for the predicate.

I think what is happening in your case is that all 50,000 records are being retrieved before the predicate is being applied. Instead, just change

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
```

and see if that improves performance.

**Edit:**

To expand on the point made by @ashutoshraina, I decided to test the two approaches to see what SQL was being generated. Using the good old Northwind database, I found the following:

**Querying with `Where(Func< T, bool>)`**

```
using (ConsoleApplication2.NorthwindEntities entities =
    new ConsoleApplication2.NorthwindEntities())
{
    Func<Product, bool> f = (p => p.Discontinued);
    var result = entities.Products.Where(f).ToList();
}
```

generated the following SQL

```
SELECT  [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID],
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName],
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID],
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit],
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice],
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock],
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder],
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel],
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
```

**Querying with `Where(Expression<Func< T, bool>>)`**

```
using (ConsoleApplication2.NorthwindEntities entities =
    new ConsoleApplication2.NorthwindEntities())
{
    Expression<Func<Product, bool>> f2 = (p => p.Discontinued);
    var result2 = entities.Products.Where(f2).ToList();
}
```

Generated the following SQL:

```
SELECT  [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID],
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName],
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID],
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID],
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit],
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice],
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock],
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder],
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel],
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1] 
    WHERE [Extent1].[Discontinued] = 1
```

This shows that using the `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` approach generated the query taking the predicate into account, thus letting SQL Server do much more of the work, which would tend to explain the issue you are experiencing using just `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: +1 I think the reason is that Expression<Func<T,bool>> executes remotely and Func<T,bool> executes locally. Hence the degraded performance.